# Onsensorchanged Gyroscope receiving no data after one minute in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

**So it works fine when the app is foreground and the first minute in the background. But after that  the listener stops receiving gyro data. But the post thread and location listener keep working.**

I tried of lot of things and I got nothing to work.

```
public final class Secret extends Service implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener {
    private final String create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(lat float, lon float, x float, y float, z float, timestamp bigint)";
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Database database;
    private Location location;

    @Override
    public final void onCreate() {
        /* Init sensor manager */
        this.sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public final int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        /* Initialize & load database */
        this.database = new Database(openOrCreateDatabase("name_data.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null));
        this.database.exec(this.create);

        /* Init location manager */
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            /* Register sensor change listener */
            this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY), SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH);

            /* Register location change listener */
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, this);
        } catch (final SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to start: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Post data every 5 minutes */
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public final void run() {
                /* Secret instance */
                final Secret secret = Secret.this;

                /* 5 minutes */
                final long time = 15000;

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        /* Wait 5 minutes */
                        Thread.sleep(time);

                        /*
                         * Unregister sensor change listener,
                         * this way posting wont cause any database errors,
                         * and the sensor events wont time out when app is running in the background
                         */
                        sensorManager.unregisterListener(secret);

                        /* Post database */
                        final int returned = post();

                        /* Register sensor change listener */
                        sensorManager.registerListener(secret, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH);

                        switch (returned) {
                            case -1:
                                System.err.println("Database too small to post");
                                break;

                            case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                                System.out.println("Posted database");
                                break;

                            default:
                                System.err.println("Post failed: " + returned);
                        }
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        System.err.println("Failed to sleep");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        /* Set thread priority and start */
        thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public final IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent event) {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        /* Store data if location is known */
        if (event == null || this.location == null) return;
        float[] gyro = event.values;

        /* Insert data into database */
        this.database.exec("INSERT INTO data(lat, lon, x, y, z, timestamp) VALUES(" + this.location.getLatitude() + "," + this.location.getLongitude() + "," + gyro[0] + "," + gyro[1] + "," + gyro[2] + "," + System.currentTimeMillis() + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public final void onAccuracyChanged(final Sensor sensor, final int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public final void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public final void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public final void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public final void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
    }

    /**
     * Post database to server
     */
    private final int post() {
        /* Check if database is large enough (8 MB) to be pushed */
        if (this.database.getFile().length() <= 8192) return -1;

        /* Push database to server */
        final int returned = Connection.post(this.database.getFile());

        /* Check if database was pushed successfully */
        if (returned == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            /* Clear database if it was pushed to server successfully */
            this.database.close();
            this.database.getFile().delete();

            /* Create new database */
            this.database = new Database(openOrCreateDatabase("name_data.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null));
            this.database.exec(this.create);
        }

        return returned;
    }
}
```

OnDestroy gets triggered and then the sensor stops giving data. the Thread and location keep running.

Comment: Can you add some logging to your lifecycle methods and check if the `onDestroy` method of the `Service` is called by the system before sensor readings stop coming?